# Docker: select ip of a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am doing a flask aplication deployed in uwsgi and nginx. My problem is that when i run it, it does in docker.internal.host and i need to specify the host. I would like to know if there is some way to create a docker network and in it, specify the host where i will see my flask application, or some other way to run a container in a specific ip.

Spected behaviour:

docker-compose up and then when i go to the ip,which i selct in docker compose.yml or in my net config, i see my flask app.

Thanks.

Comment: You could do it without toying with docker, maybe just use `iptables` and map an IP address back to your localhost - this might help https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441214/275922

Comment: If your host has multiple IP addresses, you can specify a specific one in the Docker Compose `ports:` setting or `docker run -p` option, `docker run -p 10.20.30.40:8000:80` where that's one of your host's IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
services:
  srv:
    image: image:latest
    command: start
    networks:
        mynet:
            ipv4_address: 192.168.42.11
networks:
  mynet:
    ipam:
        config:
            - subnet: 192.168.42.0/24
```

but it works only on linux and from the host where docker is running. You should consider if port mapping or the host network mode could be options for you.
check this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/